# Dropdown list to select fields to search

Tags: datatables

[DataTables](https://datatables.net/) display a search box on top-right of the table, and its nice and its working fine.

But I have a requeriment where I need a dropdown near of the search box where the user will select the field to be search.

By example, There are the columns FirstName, MiddleName and LastName. Instead of search in all the 3 columns, the user will select in the dropdown (by example "MiddleName"), and the search will happen on this field only.

Other problem is, this DataTables is populated from server-side, via ajax, and some fields on dropdown can be "server only", ie, will not be visible on DataTable. Then, on my example, just imagine the DataTable displaying "FirstName" and "LastName", but allow searching for "MiddleName". In this case, my server side code is ready, my question is only about how to setup DataTables:

1. There is some plugin/option ready for this?
2. To add this dropdown, I need create and positionate using some DataTables api?
3. How can I do to "intercept" the search button click before the request get to server, and then specify the correct column to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first part of what you asked for.  It adds the select box to the data table.  Then it takes the selected value out of the select box and adds it to the filter when ever the ajax call is triggers.

Demo at : http://live.datatables.net/zewiqiyo/1/edit

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var columns = [{ title: "Name" }, { title: "Position" }, { title: "Office" }, { title: "Age" }, { title: "Start_Date" }, { title: "Salary" }];

        // I use the preInt event to add the selectbox
        // the css has a float right for the select box so it ends up next to the filter.
        $("#example").one("preInit.dt", function () {
            $sel = $("<select></select>");
            $sel.html("<option value='-1'>Select Column</option>");
            $.each(columns, function (i, opt) {

                $sel.append("<option value='" + opt.title + "'>" + opt.title + "</option>");
            });
            $("#example_ddl").append($sel);

        });
        var table = $('#example').DataTable(
          {
              serverSide: true,
              columns: columns,
              // <"#example_ddl.filterddl"> added as a container for the selectbox
              dom: '<"#example_ddl.filterddl">fti',
              ajax: {
                  url: "examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php",
                  data: function (filter) {

                      // This is where you are intercepting what is being sent
                      // back to the server to add the column to search

                      var val = $("select", "#example_ddl").val();
                      filter.search.searchColumn = val;


                  }

              }
          }
        );
    });
```

Comment: In my own work, I actually added a second header row and put in a textbox in each one.  When the textbox was not empty, I associated it with a search in that column

Comment: In my current effort, instead of using a select box, I added a second row to the header that has textboxes. If the user entered a value then hit return, that column was searched for that value.   You can see a sample of that here http://live.datatables.net/mutafaqi/1/edit